# Can a script that was run by system command, access SESSION data of the running script?

Tags: php, apache

When scriptA.php is run by some logged in user, an in turn will call another scriptB.php using a system() or exec().

Is it possible for scriptB.php to get parameters of the SESSION data of the user that run scriptA.php in the first place ?
Thanks!

Comment: You could always pass them as CLI args, I suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it in the traditional way (using `$_SESSION`). The best way would be to pass the data as arguments to the CLI command or to write it to its `STDIN` (and read them in `scriptB.php`).

If you have permissions you could also go and read the session file (if you're handling sessions in files)... but that wouldn't be advisable.

Comment: I would add that the $argv[] array would be the way to go as pages don't own a SYSTEM array, this would make the internal command validated by the system as a system command, and not an arbitrary user generated string in the URL field. It's also advised to put scriptB.php outside of the website root folder to prevent access in another level.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant by passing data as arguments to the CLI command. The thing there is, of course, using [escapeshellarg](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) when calling `scriptB.php` to prevent dangerous injections.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about security concerns:

I'm inclined to say no. The second script won't have access to any of variables from first script.

BUT. If the server is (very) badly mis-configured, script B can try to access serialized session data from the temporary session directory used by PHP (session.save_path in php.ini).

If you want to pass data between script A and script B, you could use other ways to do it, like FIFOs, stdin, etc. Although I can't understand why you would like to execute one script from another one using exec().

Comment: scriptB takes a long time to complete, and MUST be run thoroughly. If I put scriptB outsude the website root folder, will that overcome the threat?

Comment: It's not a question of common root folder but a question of access to the PHP shared session folder (/var/lib/php5/ in debian). Under normal circumstances no script should ever be allowed to access this.

But you shouldn't use exec() to run another PHP script in first place. I'd advise you to use a queue-mechanism to run this. It's pretty easy, put the data you need in scriptB in a SQL table for example, then write a script that will constantly (using while for example) look in this table for new data and accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using standard file-based sessions, then you could have the parent script pass the session's ID to the child script as a command line parameter, e.g something like

```
shell_exec('php scriptB.php ' . session_id());
```

and then retrieve that ID within scriptB:

```
session_id($argc[1]); // argc contains command line args.
session_start();
```

I've never tried starting a session in a command-line script, so you may have to deal with cookie errors and the like. But even if you can't use session_start(), you can always access the session file directly and unserialize it, which'd be something along the lines of:

```
$sess_path = session_save_path() . '/sess_' . $argc[1];
$serialized = file_get_contents($sess_file);
$_SESSION = unserialize($serialized);
```

For other session systems, like a database, you'd access the database instead of messing with files.